# Android - How can I save user setting preferences even after the user closes the app with KOTLIN?

Tags: android, kotlin

My situation is:

I have my settings fragment. Inside my settings fragment I can change language and theme. The question is: how can i save the user settings preferences even after the user closes the application, and once the user will reopen the app, he will have the options choosed before.

Could you give me some examples? Thanks

Comment: `how can i save the user settings preferences even after the user closes the application` That is impossible. You should do such things when your app is still running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get the sharedPreferences of the app in a fragment

```
mSharedPreferences = requireActivity().getSharedPreferences("createAKey" , Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

how to get a saved sharedPreference, the second parameter is like a else
if you dont have saved before

```
var email = mSharedPreferences.getString("email_key" , "")
```

this is how you save a sharedPreference

```
mSharedPreferences.edit {
    val email = "myEmail@email.com"
    putString("email_key" , email)
}
```

}

Comment: What is precisely "createAKey" in getSharedPreferences? What do you mean with create a key? Thanks

Comment: is like a key that you will use to get the main shared preferences of your app, i always create like "app"

Comment: If I need to set like language and theme, I need two keys I suppose, right? So how can I do it? Where you store email_key? I have to create a file? Do you have a more specific example please?

Comment: create a enum with the keys, than if you are using the theme X you call the key X

Comment: i will show you a example of a project that i used before
enum class KeysShared(val key: String) {
    REMEMBERME("key_remeber"),
    APP("app"),
    USERID("key_userID"),
    RECEIVE_EMAIL("key_receive_email"),
    ACTIVE_PUSH("key_active_push"),
}
when i need a key i aways call one of these like
var userId = mSharedPreferences.getString(KeysShared.USERID.key , "")
like this the var userId will have the value that i saved before even if i close the app